# services created in ML services

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

At a client we have been using Azure Machine Learning Service (MLS) for a two projects. When making a new MLS Workspace, four services are automatically created:

•   A storage account
•   A keyvault
•   A container registry
•   En application insights

We’ve recently realized that the application insights service were created in the East US region instead of North West Europe, where the rest of the services were created. The client would like to have all their services running in North West Europe, so they’ve asked us to change it.

So my question is: Can you change “reference” in Azure Machine Learning Service from one application insights to another? I’ve been unable to find anything in this regard in the documentation. Or do we have to create a new MLS workspace in order to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can first create AppInsights in region of your choice, and then tell Azure ML to use it when creating Workspace.

To do this, pass the ARM Resource ID of the AppInsights instance to the [Workspace.create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-core/azureml.core.workspace.workspace?view=azure-ml-py#create-name--auth-none--subscription-id-none--resource-group-none--location-none--create-resource-group-true--friendly-name-none--storage-account-none--key-vault-none--app-insights-none--container-registry-none--default-cpu-compute-target-none--default-gpu-compute-target-none--exist-ok-false--show-output-true-) Python SDK command or [az ml workspace create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ext/azure-cli-ml/ml/workspace?view=azure-cli-latest#ext-azure-cli-ml-az-ml-workspace-create) CLI command.

Comment: Yes, but we would like to avoid to create a new Workspace, as we have a lot of experiments, deployed models and pipelines in the existing one and would like not to loose the history.

So we are specifically interested in knowing if it’s possible to change the ARM Resource ID for the Application Service in an existing workspace to a new one.

Comment: You would need to create a new workspace. Currently, experiments cannot be moved, but pipeline graphs and models are downloadable, so you should be able to move them to new workspace, see Model.download, Pipeline.get_graph and Graph.generate_yaml methods.